# Browse a file values to make a sum

Tags: android, listview, file-io

I have an activity that stores some data to a file and this file's data is displayed on a ListView. If i want to make the sum of a value, how can i do it? By manipulating the file ?
Here is the data stored in the file:

```
data_vidange = date + ": " + km + "km" + " " + prix + "dt "+ " "+ "\n";
```

i want to make the sum of `prix` values. Is that possible?
Thank you very much.

Comment: What value are you trying to sum. It doesn't look like you are at all trying to store in a file so much as a variable. Do you append `data_vindage` to the file? Regardless of that, if your value is in the file then, yes, you will have to read the file.

Comment: @AedonEtLIRA: can i for example just before storing the variable in the file, store it as wel in a variable that just do the job of adding the old value with the new one. Like that i'll not make a hard job of reading the whole file and filter stored values etc...

Comment: Wha-...? Ok, let me restart. `prix` is indeed a number (int, float etc...) correct?

Comment: @AedonEtLIRA: it's int .

Answer (score 0):

Your last comment suggests you have a solution, so I suspect there's more to this than we received.

Attempting a guess, do you mean that:
- you store data (which you know, based on some user input probably) in the file, but you keep the file during each run of the application; that is, it's some kind of log file growing each time you run the application
- you would like to display the sum of the price paid when you start the application, but you don't want to parse the whole file so you'd prefer to store it elsewhere?

If so, you may want to store that particular sum somewhere else (some [shared preference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) named "prixTotal" or something), so that you can access it when you (re)start the application. Of course you'll need to be careful that the sum is always accurate.

Comment: exactly, i thinked on this solution(sharedpreferences) but i really don't know how to make the sum. I want to add the input value in an EditTextPreference in a variable that it adds the value when the value of EditTextPrefence has been changed. can i make that ?

Comment: I don't see why not, but it's harder to make hypotheses on non-existing code as we don't really grasp what is blocking you. So go and try :-)